# Best indexes for this table & query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite query that must run as quickly as possible. The query is rather simple but I don't know the best way to index the table for maximum performance.

The table is called "lexicon". The definition is:

```
_id integer primary key
word text
frequency integer
lset integer
rset integer
```

The query is:

```
SELECT word,frequency FROM lexicon WHERE lset>? AND rset<? ORDER BY frequency DESC LIMIT ?
```

I've indexed all the individual columns but I suspect compound indexes may be better, but what combination? And should the indexes on lset and rset should be ascending or descending?

EDIT:
lset and rset are nested set values representing a tree structure. Therefore all values of lset and rset are mutually unique, and perfectly distributed. Also, in any given row lset < rset.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: As usual, it depends! In this case, the selectivity of the `lset` and `rset` predicates will be critical. Would `lset>?` alone likely return a greater or lesser number of records than `rset<?` alone?

Comment: Great question. I should have mentioned that lset and rset are nested set values representing a tree structure. Therefore all values of lset and rset are mutually unique, and perfectly distributed with a range of 1- 2*N (where N is the number of rows in the table).

Comment: @Barry: Do you (also) mean that the folowing is always true?: `lset <= rset`

Comment: @ypercube: In any given row, yes. Actually, lset < rset because no value appears twice (across both columns).

Comment: And the `(lset, rset)` combination is `UNIQUE`?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, but I haven't specified that in the table def.

Comment: Or you mean that if a values appears once in `lset`, it doesn't appear again, not in `lset` and neither in `rset`?

Comment: @ypercube: That's right. Each number will appear once in the table.

Comment: Ok, I see, you are using the Nested Set model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11594/discussion-between-barry-fruitman-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query (with slight changes in names):

```
SELECT word,frequency 
FROM lexicon 
WHERE lset > @LeftSide 
  AND rset < @RightSide 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT @Num
```

You are using the Nested Set model, so it could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT word,frequency 
FROM lexicon 
WHERE lset > @LeftSide          --- both `lset` here
  AND lset < @RightSide         --- and here
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT @Num
```

They could also be both `rset`. As long as your data does not violate the Nested Set model, both will work and give same results. So, your query may need a covering index on the 3 columns:

```
(lset, frequency, word)
```

It will use the index to identify the (possibly thousands) rows that fall into the `(@LeftSide,@RightSide)` range and then use a filesort to find the (@Num) words with top frequency.

An index on `(frequency DESC, lset, word)` may be better in some cases (it really does depend on the parameter values), so it's good if you have that index as well. But I can't answer on whether SQLite will peak the best index on every instance.

Depending on how many rows fall into that range, it may perform from well to not so well. But I don't see an easy way to optimize further this kind of query.

Comment: Thanks for the query optimization. I see now that rset is not really necessary. I updated the query and indexed the table as you suggested but it's still not fast enough. I suspect, as you do, that it cannot be optimized further.

Comment: Great news: I was using the wrong index (the columns were in the wrong order) and after arranging them correctly the query is 5-10x faster. I think now it is fast enough for my purposes. :):):)

Comment: @Barry: I have posted a related question at dba.se: [Performance of query with a range condition and order by](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/performance-of-query-with-a-range-condition-and-order-by). Feel free to follow that and make comments there.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to depend the statistics of your data.

You could try creating indexes on every combination of `lset`, `rset` and `frequency` to find the best case, but you *must* then have real data in your table.
- (`lset`, `rset`, `frequency`)
- (`rset`, `lset`, `frequency`)
- (`lset`, `frequency`, `rset`)
- (`rset`, `frequency`, `lset`)
- (`frequency`, `lset`, `rset`)
- (`frequency`, `rset`, `lset`)

The advantage of having `frequency` first is that it's already prepared for your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.

But if every word in your lexicon happens to have a different frequency the second and third fields in the index will become worthless.  *(An example of why the statistics of your data matters.)*

It also matters as to which field will limit you records the fastest.  If the `lset < x` filter reduces the set to `0.01%` of the original size, put that filter first in your index.

But in all likelyhood, filtering `lset < X and rset > y` will be impossible to index very well at all.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, if Sqlite behaves like other DBMSs, adding `word` as the final column in the index would make the index cover all of the required fields and avoid any need to lookup that column elsewhere. This would not help if this index clusters the table.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw - Agreed.  Finding a data field that's not in an index is similar to adding an extra join...  `JOIN theIndex On blah JOIN theTable ON theIndex.PK = theTable.PK`.  Including the necessary fields in the index therefore removes this overhead.  *(Except in Clustered Indexes where the Table IS the Index.)*

Comment: @Dems I'm not sure if SQLite supports that, but in "big" DBMSes you can mix the "orientation" of index components, so `lset>? AND rset<?` **can** actually be indexed efficiently.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - That's correct. But it still won't help as much as one would hope. By example, pretend both `lset` and `rset` are scored as integers from `0` to `99`. The index entry for `lset = 0` will then have a hundred `rset` entries under it. For each `lset` that passes the seach condition *(on average 50%, naively?)*, there needs to be another index seek to check the `rset` predicate *(1 lset seek, 50 rset seeks)*. It's not nearly as effective as `lset > x AND lset < y`. Especially when considering that `lset` and `rset` will likely have a *huge* range of legitimate values.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. I just added some extra info to my question that I should have included originally (sorry). The table represents a tree structure and lset/rset are nested set pairs, so: 1. in any given row lset<rset. 2. Every value of lset and rset is unique, and 3. they are perfectly distributed from 1-2*N (N=rows in table). 4. Frequency is not unique and has a logarithmic distribution (it represents the frequency of word usage in a language). Branko's answer below seems very promising (thanks Branko). Does anyone agree or disagree?

Answer (score 2):

If SQLite behaves simlarly to other DBMSes in this regard, you'll need a composite index on...

```
{lset, rset DESC, frequency DESC}
```

...in this specific order and with these specific `DESC` clauses.

Take a look at [this article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/order-by-asc-desc-nulls-last) for more info on ascending/descending indexes.

---

And yes, as @DanielRenshaw mentioned, you could include `word` at the end of the index, purely to allow [index-only scan](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index). This is known as "covering" index.

*(Since clustering index already covers all fields, there is no purpose of doing that for such an index.)*